# How do I convert my data from firestore into authentication users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, zapier

I use Zapier to get the answers from a Google Forms and move them into a Firestore Collection, but I need to get this data (which includes name, password and email) and turn it into users on the Firebase Authentication Module, is there a way to automatically do that?

I need the sign up to be done exclusively with the Google Forms, but I only know how to do the inverse way (authentication into firestore).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Cloud Function which is [triggered when a new document is created in the Firestore collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created).

Let's imagine the collection that is populated by Zapier is named `usersCreationRequests`. The following Cloud Function will do the trick:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    
admin.initializeApp();
    
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('usersCreationRequests/{userDocId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
  
        return admin
            .auth()
            .createUser({
                email: snap.get('email'),
                password: snap.get('password'),
                displayName: snap.get('name')
            })
            .then((userRecord) => {
                console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
                return null;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
                return null;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Using the `userDocId` as Firebase Auth UID might be good idea too :D

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, that might be interesting, but we don't have any detail from the OP on this point.

Comment: bruh i just discovered that i need to pay to use cloud functions?? but im just a poor dev T_T man this world aint far

Comment: You don't **have to** pay, you need a credit card but there is a very generous free tier and if you don't go over the limit you will not pay anything.

Comment: thank you very much i will do that and talk with my mom about signing cloud functions, since im only 17 and dont really have a credit card to use on my own, and this project im doing is for her. But you helped me a lot, i appreciate it <3